# Is the comment in the jQuery promises example misleading?

Tags: jquery, promise

The comment in the example on the [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) says:

```
var div = $( "<div>" );

div.promise().done(function( arg1 ) {
  // Will fire right away and alert "true"
  alert( this === div && arg1 === div );
});
```

But that's not exactly correct, is it?  It will pop up an alert box so quickly that you will *think* it fired right away, but in reality, the next line of code will get executed and then whenever the promise is done, it will pop up the alert box, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you're looking at says this in the above caption:

> Using .promise() on a collection with no active animation returns a
>   resolved Promise:

They're trying to demonstrate that this returns a resolved promise immediately

Answer (score 1):

This is another thing unique to jQuery promises, with proper promises implementation deterministic execution order is guaranteed.

So yes, it will fire right away synchronously*. This means common patterns like caching require additional care to ensure code is not affected by essentially random execution order.

For example the following code cannot be used because the results are random:

```
console.log(1);
//uses ajax first then further requests are cached for 5-10 minutes:
getData().then(function(data) {
    console.log(3);
});
console.log(2);
```

Also this means jQuery promises are susceptible to stack overflow when a lot of promises are used in sequence.

*There is no benefit from this either, stackoverflow and non-determinism can be avoided efficiently by using light weight scheduler like MutationObserver and trampoline.